# Swift: Background gradient for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm having trouble trying to add a gradient background to  `UIView`. I made an `extension` of `UIView` and added the following method:

```
func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor) {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

**Then I call:**

```
separatorView.setGradientBackground(colorTop: .clear, colorBottom: .red)
```

But it doesn't work. The view is presented but its background is entirely clear. I tried as well with `CGColor`

Comment: try this, https://github.com/matvdg/Gradient-View

Comment: the code works fine, check the rest of your code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There were 2 problems:

- I needed to set the start and end points to provide a gradient direction:

  ```
  func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor) {
      let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
      gradientLayer.colors = [colorBottom.cgColor, colorTop.cgColor]
      gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
      gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
      gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
      gradientLayer.frame = bounds

     layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
  }
  ```
- And the second issue was that `CAGradientLayer` takes effect after the view is layed out. I solved that calling `setGradientBackground()` on `viewDidAppear`:

  ```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      separatorView.setGradientBackground(colorTop: .clear, colorBottom: Colors.darkGrey)
  }
  ```

Comment: why u actually accepted your answer, instead of Moayad's? seems like he answered faster.

Comment: Re second issue: it's actually because the view geometry is set when viewDidAppear(_:) is called. You can, and probably should, call setGradientBackground(colorTop:colorBottom:) elsewhere, for example viewDidLoad(), otherwise you could be adding multiple gradient layers. You just need to make sure to update the gradient layer frame whenever the geometry is set in viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Answer (score 15):

Update your method to the code blow:

```
func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor){
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop.cgColor, colorBottom.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.locations = [NSNumber(floatLiteral: 0.0), NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0)]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds

    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Moayad's answer worked best for me but it was backwards with top color as bottom so i reversed the function he posted.

**Swift 4**

```
    func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor){
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorBottom.cgColor, colorTop.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For @IBDesignable: You can custom your UI on storyboard. It is easier to use.

```
@IBDesignable class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = .blue {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = .green {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = .yellow {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowX: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowY: CGFloat = -3 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowBlur: CGFloat = 3 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var startPointX: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var startPointY: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var endPointX: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var endPointY: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let gradientLayer = layer as! CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: startPointX, y: startPointY)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: endPointX, y: endPointY)
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowX, height: shadowY)
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowBlur
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain that how to set Start X, start Y, End X and End Y. ???

Answer (score 3):

The code works fine. However, you should call it at `layoutSubviews`.

### Swift 5

```
class ViewExample: UIView {

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        configureGradientLayer()
    }

    func configureGradientLayer(){
        backgroundColor = .clear
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.systemPurple.cgColor, UIColor.systemPink.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0, 1]
        gradient.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This does work for my project

```
/**
 set a gradient to a view
 gradientColors must be cgColors
 gradientColors and locations must have the same array size
 example:
 let gradientColors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
 let locations:[NSNumber] = [0.0,0.8,1.0]
 */
static func setGradient(viewWithGradient: UIView, backgroundColor: UIColor, gradientColors: [CGColor], locations:[NSNumber], boundsOfGradient:CGRect) {

    if gradientColors.count != locations.count {
        print("gradientColors and locations must have same size!")
        return
    }

    viewWithGradient.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    let mask = CAGradientLayer()
    mask.colors = gradientColors
    mask.locations = locations
    mask.frame = boundsOfGradient
    viewWithGradient.layer.mask = mask
}
```

Call like this

```
    let gradientColors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor,UIColor.yellow.cgColor]
    let locations:[NSNumber] = [0.0,0.8,1.0]
    GeneralTools.setGradient(viewWithGradient: yourViewThatShouldGetGradient, backgroundColor: backgroundColorOfYourViewWithGradient, gradientColors: gradientColors, locations: locations, boundsOfGradient: viewWhereIsYourGradientInside.bounds)
```

Maybe not clear enough `boundsOfGradient`: The bounds will be set to your gradients frame. So simply said this will declare the size of your gradient.

Answer (score 1):

gmoraleda's answer is correct. Do this on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if you're using AutoLayout.